# Keep UIButton highlighted after touch & iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, ios7, compatibility

I need like to keep a `UIButton` highlighted after a touch event. In iOS versions < 7 I used the following action for the Touch Up Inside event:

```
- (IBAction)clickMe:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = sender;
    [NSOperationQueue.mainQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{ button.highlighted = YES; }];
}
```

Unfortunately something has changed in iOS 7 and this code doesn't work anymore: if I tap the button, the button reverts to normal state; interestingly, if I keep the button pressed for a little longer, the button remains highlighted. Please note that the app was developed for iOS 6 so it runs in iOS 7 in compatibility mode. I'm trying to figure out a way to make the app work properly on both iOS 6 & 7 but so far I haven't found a nice solution (one workaround is to queue an event that highlights the button after a short delay but that produces an annoying flickering of the button). Any advice?

Answer (score 4):

[As for the "`.highlighted`" property you're using, Apple documentation states](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIControl/highlighted): "UIControl automatically sets and clears this state automatically when a touch enters and exits during tracking and when there is a touch up."

Why not change the UIImage that your UIButton displays, depending on the "state" you want it to appear in?  I would subclass UIButton, give it a state property that you can control or set, and depending on that state you can show a different image.

Comment: You're right @Wolfy.  Let me think of a slightly reworded answer.

Comment: Michael, yes I know how the `.highlighted` property works but thanks for pointing that out. Queueing an operation like I do used to override the default behavior because the operation would occur after the Touch Up event reset the `.highlighted` back to NO. It was a trick, but it was simple and effective. Unfortunately iOS 7 has changed the order of operations, apparently. Of course subclassing the `UIButton` class would solve the problem but I was looking for a simple solution. Also, I'm not using images, just title text.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                     animations:^{
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         button.highlighted = true;
                         button.selected = true;
                     }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit late to help you, but what I finally ended up doing to get around this issue is to set the layer background color to grey in the block for setting the button highlighted.  And then when I set the highlight state to false, I set the background color back to white.  For this to work, you have to use a custom button, not a rounded rect button.